# Why's my fridge gasket so sticky, even after wiping it with warm soap water?

Tags: refrigerator

I'm asking just chiller gasket of my single-door Frigidaire fridge like [this](https://youtu.be/SE4iKCIfesQ?t=7), bought new in 2015. I ask NOT the freezer gasket because it's not sticky and works normally. No food or liquid is leaking.

3 weeks ago, chiller gasket got sticky! It clings to chiller more tightly than usual. I have to use more force to pull chiller door open, and when it opens, I hear a much louder sound when suction pulls away.

[image]

1. I don't know how describe this sound. Any ideas?

> [If you find a place on the fridge seal (also referred to as the gasket) where air may be leaking because of gunk or other buildup, you can usually remedy the situation fairly easily by just giving the affected area a wipedown with warm soap and water on a rag.](https://greenlivingideas.com/2014/07/29/check-seal-fridge-oven/)

[image]

I wiped down gasket 8 times now! 3 weeks ago, first I wiped with warm soap water just like quote. Second time, I wiped with just warm water rinse.

2. I repeated this 2 weeks ago, 1 week ago, and yesterday.  But chiller gasket still sticky! Why?

Comment: How old is it? Sometimes the rubber breaks down with age (which can be aggravated by exposure to various chemicals or pollutants) and you just have to replace it. Hmm. From some other "sticky rubber" issues I recall that ammonia might be of particular use for certain types of sticky rubber surface degradation.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks. I added year. I bought it new in 2015.

Comment: Have you cleaned the body of the fridge (chiller) where the magnetic gasket touches it when the door is closed?  It may be the source of the stickiness.

Comment: I've run into the  "unexpected sticky rubber" thing before, and as above mentioned I think it's breakdown of the materials.      I've had success de-stickifying them with "Goo Gone"    https://googone.com/    Clean up the remaining Goo Gone residue with a little 70% isopropyl alcohol

Comment: @Kyle B Isopropyl alcohol by itself works about as well as Goo Gone in many scenarios, especially if you’re planning to clean up Goo Gone with isopropyl, you might try foregoing the Goo Gone.